# How to learn Backtracking-recursion without knowledge of structs? - c

Tags: c, recursive-backtracking

edit: someone brought to my attention- that SO isn't the place to ask for tutorials.
If so I'd be glad if someone could explain to me how to implement recursive backtracking using arrays (I don't know how to use linked lists etc.)

**TL;DR**: Looking for books or sites which teach backtracking recursion in **C** without knowledge of data structures.

Hey,
I am taking a course in c programming language and one of the questions on the exam will ask as to implement backtracking using recursion.

Problem is, the course doesn't cover structs or def type or linked lists or any of that jazz, but every book I read in order to understand backtracking recursion talks about linked lists and structs, which I know nothing about and am not supposed to implement in my code on the exam.

Can anyone here point me to a book/site which can explain this concept of backtracking recursion without structs or anything like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but requests for book and tutorial recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: These concepts are orthogonal to data structures. Basic recursion can be seen calculating Fibonacci numbers. Backtracking - searching for a move in a tick-tac-toe game.

Comment: By the way, `struct` in C has a very loose connection to a computer science "Data structure" concept.

Comment: *a course in c programming language ... doesn't cover structs*. This isn't a course of C. More like a travesty of one. Demand your tuition money back.

Comment: @n.m. I just want to get a good grade, really LOL
Looking at past exams, they did teach it in this course, but decided to stop doing that around 2014...

Comment: If you want grades, stay. If you want knowledge, run away. Can you post a link to the course?

Comment: @n.m. What I really want is knowledge in Electrical Engineering and Physics which is my degree...

Comment: These are the lecture slides (sorry, they are in Hebrew)
https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234114/Winter2018-2019/ho_Lecture%20slides.html
These are the tutorials :
https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234114/Winter2018-2019/ho_Tutorial%20slides.html

Comment: This is not a C course. This is an introduction to computer science with some minimal exposure to C. You as a Technion student is suposed to just learn yourself what the course doesn't cover. Get a book, spend an evening. Done.

Comment: @n.m. I suppose I will. Just out of curiosity, how do you know about this school?

Comment: I happen to have some ties with it. Anyway, the backtracking tutorial you linked seems to be reasonably good and thorough. If you have any specific problem with the tutorial, you are welcome to ask questions about it.

Comment: Backtracking is actually a "brute force technique" to solve some task. Usually demonstrated with [Eight queens puzzle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), which in fact, needs only arrays. Hire is [C implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/)

Comment: And it seems like your course - is for the first semester 0-ro beginner student. It should have at least a second part with structs, sorting, searching, dynamic arrays, single and double linked lists and binary search trees etc. Or you should have another discrete mathematics course which cover this.

Comment: If not check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)

Comment: Tahnk you all :)